# Changing typeface of text in a WebView

Tags: android, webview, typeface

I looked around on StackOverflow and it looks like all of the questions related to changing the typeface also concerned using custom fonts. Is it possible to just change the typeface to Serif in a WebView without changing the font as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. In the HTML content, in the head do:

```
<html>
<head>
...
<style type="text/css">
body { font-family: serif; }
...
</style>
...
```